# Best way of updating Openssl on Linux machine

Tags: linux, yum, linux-kernel, openssl

I have a confusion to choose the best way for upgrading the OpenSSL on my Linux machine.

**1**Through the yum Update.****

```
# yum update
```

I know this will update the entire packages. But If I want to specifically update OpenSSL

```
Can I use # yum update OpenSSL
```

**2. Through the commands**

```
$ openssl version

$ wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0i.tar.gz

$ tar xzvf openssl-1.0.0i.tar.gz

$ cd openssl-1.0.0i

$ make clean

$ ./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl

$ make

$ make test

$ make install
```

Please suggest me the best approach.

Thanks.